# How to define functions that will apply to multiple lists in Python?

Tags: string, list, function, python-3.x

I'm a beginner to Python. I'm trying to create a poker game in which a 5x5 grid of playing cards is dealt out, then the player can shift any row or column left/right or up/down, respectively.

I've decided to represent this with five lists of five strings. (Although, if you have a better idea, I'll be happy to hear it). So a starting board might look like:

```
['Ks', '5h', 'Ts', '3s', '7h']
['As', '9d', '5c', 'Jd', '8c']
['9s', '6h', '6d', '3c', '2c']
['Qd', '8h', 'Jh', '2d', 'Td']
['4h', 'Kd', 'Qs', '5d', '9c']
```

The player might choose to move the top row one space to the left, which would give a board like so:

```
['5h', 'Ts', '3s', '7h', 'Tc']
['As', '9d', '5c', 'Jd', '8c']
['9s', '6h', '6d', '3c', '2c']
['Qd', '8h', 'Jh', '2d', 'Td']
['4h', 'Kd', 'Qs', '5d', '9c']
```

The left-most card is dropped off, and a new card is added from the deck on the right. The player can then repeat this for any row or column until the deck runs out of cards.

What I'm having trouble with is defining functions that would apply for *any* of these lists, as opposed to having to create five near-duplicates for anything I want to do.

So I start with a list (called "deck") of all the playing cards, and five empty lists, named row0 to row4. To generate the starting board, I'm currently going:

```
def drawRight0():
    card = random.randint(0,len(deck)-1)
    row0.append(deck[card])
    del deck[card]

def drawRight1():
    card = random.randint(0,len(deck)-1)
    row1.append(deck[card])
    del deck[card]

...

def firstBoard():
    for i in range (5):
        drawRight0(), drawRight1(), drawRight2(), drawRight3(), drawRight4()
```

Surely I should be able to simplify this to some equivalent of "rowx.append", but I can't figure it out.

It's a similar story for the game moves. If I want to define how to move a row to the left, I can do:

```
def shiftLeft0():
    for i in range(4):
        row0[i] = row0[i+1]
    del row1[4]
    drawLeft1()
```

... for every row, but that too seems inefficient.

Finally, shifting cards up and down is a bit trickier. Currently, I'm working with functions like:

```
def shiftUp0():
    row0[0] = row1[0]
    row1[0] = row2[0]
    row2[0] = row3[0]
    row3[0] = row4[0]
    del row4[0]
    card = random.randint(0,len(deck)-1)
    row4.insert(0,deck[card])
    del deck[card]
```

I should be able to loop the first four lines (although it's not a huge deal). But again, the main issue is needing to define different function for each column, like I also need to do this:

```
def shiftUp3():
        row0[3] = row1[3]
        row1[3] = row2[3]
        row2[3] = row3[3]
        row3[3] = row4[3]
        del row4[3]
        card = random.randint(0,len(deck)-1)
        row4.insert(0,deck[card])
        del deck[card]
```

I'm thinking that maybe I should do something with a list of lists, like

```
rows = [row0, row1, row2, row3, row4]
```

...but I'm not sure how I would then go about applying that in the way I want.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Your function should take the list to operate on as a parameter. Your calls would then look like `drawright(row0)` or `drawright(rows[0])`, depending on whether you use a list of rows or not.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very difficult way of working with a 5x5 board. You could do this more easily by having a list containing 5 lists, each with 5 values, instead of having 5 separate lists, like you mention at the end of your post. That can be created like this:

`board = [[0 for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]`
You can then work with the board like you'd normally access the values in lists:

`board[0][0] = 1
board[1][1] = 2
board
 --> [[1,0,0,0,0],[0,2,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]`
I think you can work out how to solve the problem fairly easily given that much, feel free to ask for more help if something isn't clear or you get stuck.